# Running a Ruby script via web

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am following the [Rails Tutorial by Michael Hart](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial#cha-sign_up) and I am already on Chapter 7. But I wanna do something different right now, which the tutorial doesn't teach. I wanna run a script file inside my webpage. How I can do that? I saw other posts here saying to use Sinatra, but since I am following this tutorial I don't think it is such a good idea to use it because it can make everything different from the tutorial.

Here is the simple script I wanna run on my webpage:

```
#Somando idades

def soma_vetor_excluindo(index,vet)   
    soma = 0   
    for i in 0..9
        if(i!=index)
            soma = soma + vet[i].to_i
        end   
    end   
    return soma 
end

def soma_vetor(vet)   
    soma = 0   
    for i in 0..9
        soma = soma + vet[i].to_i   
    end   
    return soma 
end

def maior_vetor(vet)   
    maior = 0   
    for i in 0..9
        if(maior < vet[i])
            maior = vet[i]
        end   
    end   
    return maior 
end

idades = (0..9).collect{rand(99)+1}

soma_idades = (0..9).collect{0} soma = 0

print "#{idades} \n"

for i in 0..9   
    soma_idades[i] = soma_vetor_excluindo(i,idades) 
end

print "#{soma_idades} \n"

div = soma_vetor(soma_idades) / 9

resp = div - maior_vetor(soma_idades)

puts "#{resp}"
```

Comment: for i in x isn't the 'Ruby' way. You'll want to change it to (0..9).each { |i| my_method(i) } or "do/end" if it's multiline.

Comment: Also, look at Ruby's inject method for summing an array and for getting the highest value you can arr.sort{|x,y|y<=>x}.first Now, where do you want the output from print and puts to show up? If you want to program client side (in the users' browser) you use javascript.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to do it would be to make the method `soma_vetor_excluindo`, `soma_vetor`, `maior_vetor`, etc, controller methods, so when you send data through a form or ajax, the action would trigger, calculate the values and return you a result.

Knowing this, you can have a controller, let's say `MathController.rb`, and inside it, the `soma_vetor_excluindo` method:

```
class MathController < ApplicationController
  def soma_vetor_excluindo
  end
  def soma_vetor
  end
  def maior_vetor
  end
end
```

To access this, you probably need a `route`, so on your `routes.rb` add something like this:

```
get 'math/soma_vetor_excluindo/:index/:vet', to 'math#soma_vetor_excluindo'
get 'math/soma_vetor/:vet', to 'math#soma_vetor'
get 'math/maior_vetor/:vet', to 'math#maior_vetor'
```

This means that when your browser hit `localhost/math/soma_vetor_excluindo/1/2` or the other urls, it would send a get request to the controller calling the `soma_vetor_excluindo` method and putting in the parameters, `params[:index]` and `params[:vet]`, so theoretically the script would run.

The thing is, you can adapt your controller to do something like this with very little work.

Comment: How I can make "soma_vetor_excluindo" a controller method?

Comment: I used `calculate` just to simplify things. You can call it `soma_vetor_excluindo`. Lemme edit it.

Comment: First of all, thanks for helping me out! But I still can't figure out how to solve this. Maybe I am too newbie.Here is how it is looking right now:

I created a static page for the script called "2011question6"

So on my static_pages_controller.rb I got
    `def minigame
    @title = "2011question6"
  end`

I've created the MathController as you said. But if I insert what you said to routes.rb my website breaks. So I don't know what to put on routes.rb. Right now I'm only with the static page on routes.rb

  `match '/2011question6page', to: 'static_pages#2011question6page', via: 'get'`

Comment: I do this when I need to access certain services on my server. In my case, I have urls like `admin/:service.:action => "admin#service"` so if the authenticated user goes to something like `admin/mailer.restart` it will call my admin controller's service action. From there, I put the logic to stop, start, restart, or whatever the specified service.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the simplest solution is to load a page per script. First you add a path for your script into the `routes.rb` with something like:

```
get 'scripts/your_script', to 'scripts#your_script
```

And in the controller (app/scripts_controller.rb) you should add your code like this:

```
class ScriptsController < ApplicationController
  #Somando idades

  def soma_vetor_excluindo(index,vet)   
    soma = 0   
    for i in 0..9
        if(i!=index)
            soma = soma + vet[i].to_i
        end   
    end   
    return soma 
  end

  def soma_vetor(vet)   
    soma = 0   
    for i in 0..9
        soma = soma + vet[i].to_i   
    end   
    return soma 
  end

  def maior_vetor(vet)   
    maior = 0   
    for i in 0..9
        if(maior < vet[i])
            maior = vet[i]
        end   
    end   
    return maior 
  end

  def your_script
    idades = (0..9).collect{rand(99)+1}
    soma_idades = (0..9).collect{0} 
    soma = 0

    answer = "#{idades} \n"
    for i in 0..9   
      soma_idades[i] = soma_vetor_excluindo(i,idades) 
    end

    answer << "#{soma_idades} \n"

    div = soma_vetor(soma_idades) / 9
    resp = div - maior_vetor(soma_idades)
    answer << "#{resp}"

    render(text: answer)
  end
end
```

when you access the page `scripts/your_script`, it should render a plain text presentation of your script result.

Although this is not the most elegant solution, it should solve your problem.